# Regards To Automatically Clicking a Button on my website

Tags: jquery, python, automation

I have a button on my website on terranbailey.com/bio that's at the bottom, that indicates "click here" what I'm looking for is a function that can automatically click that button after the page load up? I've been searching high and low for answers. I determined that I may just need to ask the question myself that pertains to my website to better help produce a code personalized.

Kind regards.

Comment: In your "searching high and low," what have you come up with? It won't be too useful to you if we just give you ideas of what you've already tried. Also, what medium are you programming through? Where would this button-clicking code go?

Comment: So you've considered an `onload` handler that calls the button's `.click()` method?

Comment: inside document.ready you can trigger your button whats a problem ?

Comment: On my search high and low I concluded that I'm an idiot when it comes to coding. All i want is for my button (that says click here at the bottom of the page) on my website terranbailey.com/bio to automatically trigger a click after the page load up. I'm working on squarespace so my button isn't html from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Your website should at least must support javascript, so, to programmatically click that button you need to user the event "onload" in the element body, something like this:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById("mybutton").click()">
```

"onload" will run when body element has charged.

Comment: I'm using squarespace. I can't even find the html for my button. Sorry, but I'm clueless to the html /javascript coding so hats off to whoever is genius enough to figure this out. I simply want the button on www.terranbailey.com/bio where it says "click here" to automatically click after the page load up

Comment: I'm using squarespace. I can't even find the html for my button. Sorry, but I'm clueless to the html /javascript coding so hats off to whoever is genius enough to figure this out. I simply want the button on www.terranbailey.com/bio where it says "click here" to automatically click after the page load up @diegoe

Comment: @MerlotB I see, ummm, I found that in squarespace you can inject javascript code, so, you should use "window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("mybutton").click()}", the problem is the id of the button element, I really don't know if you can edit your html code.

Comment: squarespace code injection https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908

Comment: I don't think I can edit it. However, I can inject a code so I may have to manually create an HTML code (button) and attribute it an "id" I assume

Comment: Hey, I manually created the HTML button however when I go to the page, nothing automatically does anything. Is there something I'm missing or maybe doing wrong?

Comment: @MerlotB, I saw what you did, I found an space in the onload function, check that: document.getElementById(" submit_btn").click(), remove the space at the beginning of the id "submit_btn" and it will work.

Comment: Hey I don't see a space in it. Perhaps I'm doing it wrong. I may need someone to physically do it for me lol I'm cluelss when it comes to this. I'm sorry, I don't see any space

Comment: Very frustrating cause you'd probably be able to do it if you had my access

Comment: write me to diegoenrik at gmail and I`ll help you

Comment: Ok, I sent you an email from tbaileyofficial. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You also have this question tagged under Python and automation, so if you need to automate this process from Python, you will want to look into the [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage) library. Selenium will open up a browser of your choice, navigate to a website, and perform any actions on the website you tell it to do. In this case after you install the Selenium library `pip install selenium`, and you install the associated [driver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#drivers), you will want to use the following code to click your button.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # opens a new browser window controlled by selenium
driver.get("https://your-website.com") # navigate to your website
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#submit_btn').click() # And click the button
```

Edit:

I see you have the code `$(function () { window.onload = $('#submit_btn').click(); });` at the bottom of your website. That's the correct code, but there are a few modifications that need to be made. JavaScript code/jquery code needs to be put inside of  tags, otherwise it'll spit the characters back out without executing any code.

The other issue is that jQuery does not come preloaded. You have to add the following line of code somewhere in your website to load jQuery.

```
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

So altogether your code would look like this:

```
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
  $(function () { window.onload = $('#submit_btn').click(); }
</script>
```

But you don't actually need to wait until the window is loaded, you only need the DOM loaded, which means all of the HTML has been loaded and parsed by the browser, but the browser has not necessarily finished displaying the website and executing any other code that may be on the website. This is done with the document.ready function which is usually preferred over the window.load function because you don't have to wait as long to start executing code that has to do  with the HTML on the page. SO for example you could do

```
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#submit_btn').click();
});
</script>
```

But we can do even better. We don't need to use jQuery at all. jQuery is a compilation of functions that add aditional functionality to JavaScript and makes it easier to work with JavaScript, but for something so simple we really don't need to waste time loading the entire jQuery library. Instead if you place the script tag after your submit button, you can simply do the following.

```
<!-- Make sure this is after the submit button because it's kind of difficult to click a button if the button doesn't exist yet. -->
<script>
  window.document.getElementById("submit_btn").click();
</script>
```

There is one last thing you will need to do to make everything work. The click here button does not have an id associated with it. You'll want to change the line 
`<a href="/gallery" class="sqs-block-button-element--medium sqs-block-button-element" data-initialized="true">Click Here</a>`

to

`<a href="/gallery" class="sqs-block-button-element--medium sqs-block-button-element" data-initialized="true"`**`id="submit_btn"`**`>Click Here</a>`

This will allow you to select it from jQuery/JavaScript

P.S. With ad blocker turned off, I'm getting some malicious ad trying to get me to download spyware.

Comment: Ok maybe my solution is a bit more simple. Spare me please, I am new to this coding world. All I'm looking for is how I can find the proper html for my button on my site and automatically be able to click on it after the page loads. terranbailey.com/bio have a look

Comment: In that case there's no need to tag the question with Python or automation as you cannot send Python code over the web, and automation usually refers to creating code that automatically performs complicated tasks that would otherwise have to be manually done by somebody in the company, for example, creating code that runs a whole bunch of tests against an app with selenium so a QA engineer doesn't have to manually perform thousands of tasks that verify changes to the codebase are not going to break everything. Anyhow, back to your main question... I'll revise my question to answer your problem

Comment: Hey, I tried the code but for some reason when I load the website it isn't doing it properly. (Nothing happens) I don't know if I missed anything? I realized there really isn't a set timer to how long you have to be on the page for the click button to automatically trigger and click. When I incorporated the code for a new click here button it just gave me a new link to click instead of the previous click here button. I really need assistance as I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong. Squarespace is a bit tricky when it comes to code injection cause it's a premade template design website.

Comment: Also, I'm confused how the final code should look. That wasn't clear to me. You're saying I don't have to use jquery at all, and I think that completely threw me off.

Comment: When I copy the code, it isn't even closing properly and it still indicates text outside of the script function it's actually accepting.